# How to get html wrapper of some loose text with jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I want to get html wrapper of some loose text with jquery.

In the code, I am not getting any id or any unique thing, but getting only text in the . for e.g. 'hello world' . Now I want to is give some background to the , which has this text 'Hello world'.

So from text, how can i get the wrapper html of it, which i can then use in jquery and add some css to it..

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i was just thinking of getting it through textNode or something like that.. but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery **:contains** selector for achieving what you need.

Jquery documentation for contains reads "Select all elements that contain the specified text."

```
<div>test</div>

<script>
$("div:contains('test')").addClass("test-class");
</script>
```

Above code will find the div and add class to the div.

You can adjust your html selector accordingly. In my code I have used div tag , you may need to have your selector accordingly.

It will also search the text from child elements, so adjust you selector accordingly and use parent() selector if needed.

Note: It's case sensitive